# How to set a navigation header with fixed position at the top

Tags: html, css

I'm setting a navigation header to fixed position at the top of the page. The problem is that right aligned items will be partially hidden when there is a scrollbar. How do i prevent this from happening?

My code

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="mat-elevation-z1" fxLayout="row">
  <span style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>
  <div>Right Item</div>
</header>
```

this is how the above code appears. i want the right item to be fully displayed when the scollbar shows. when there is no scrollbar, it does fully show.
[image]

Comment: `header: { padding-right: 15px; }`

Comment: this can't be all your code.. nothing says that the div should be floated/positioned to the right?

Comment: it is all of the code @Livo i have set position to fixed in code and the width to 100%

Comment: @AndyHoffman is it possible to do it without using padding. And using 15px still leaves the content partially hidden

Comment: @MelvinOtieno This is what padding is for. It sounds like you haven't set `box-sizing: border-box;` in `header`. It's hard to tell for sure without a link to the working site/webpage.

Comment: @AndyHoffman actually it now works thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to accomplish it using `padding` and `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  
  /* Added the following lines */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header class="mat-elevation-z1" fxLayout="row">
  <span style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>
  <div>Right Item</div>
</header>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure debitis corporis cum nemo ex, soluta hic ratione obcaecati corrupti quas quod, laborum itaque consequatur, sint enim voluptatum dolore aliquam eum. Doloribus perspiciatis non debitis cum cumque
  iste magnam architecto labore, veritatis fugit omnis eius maiores earum molestias aliquam facilis sint ea facere corrupti quae placeat deserunt incidunt eveniet ad! Aut. Itaque atque minus dignissimos nostrum earum modi, nemo error, placeat est quas
  deserunt ducimus magni. Facilis cumque aspernatur esse explicabo ea sit incidunt molestiae tempore? Laudantium molestiae qui obcaecati dignissimos?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure debitis corporis cum nemo ex, soluta hic ratione obcaecati corrupti quas quod, laborum itaque consequatur, sint enim voluptatum dolore aliquam eum. Doloribus perspiciatis non debitis cum cumque
  iste magnam architecto labore, veritatis fugit omnis eius maiores earum molestias aliquam facilis sint ea facere corrupti quae placeat deserunt incidunt eveniet ad! Aut. Itaque atque minus dignissimos nostrum earum modi, nemo error, placeat est quas
  deserunt ducimus magni. Facilis cumque aspernatur esse explicabo ea sit incidunt molestiae tempore? Laudantium molestiae qui obcaecati dignissimos?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure debitis corporis cum nemo ex, soluta hic ratione obcaecati corrupti quas quod, laborum itaque consequatur, sint enim voluptatum dolore aliquam eum. Doloribus perspiciatis non debitis cum cumque
  iste magnam architecto labore, veritatis fugit omnis eius maiores earum molestias aliquam facilis sint ea facere corrupti quae placeat deserunt incidunt eveniet ad! Aut. Itaque atque minus dignissimos nostrum earum modi, nemo error, placeat est quas
  deserunt ducimus magni. Facilis cumque aspernatur esse explicabo ea sit incidunt molestiae tempore? Laudantium molestiae qui obcaecati dignissimos?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure debitis corporis cum nemo ex, soluta hic ratione obcaecati corrupti quas quod, laborum itaque consequatur, sint enim voluptatum dolore aliquam eum. Doloribus perspiciatis non debitis cum cumque
  iste magnam architecto labore, veritatis fugit omnis eius maiores earum molestias aliquam facilis sint ea facere corrupti quae placeat deserunt incidunt eveniet ad! Aut. Itaque atque minus dignissimos nostrum earum modi, nemo error, placeat est quas
  deserunt ducimus magni. Facilis cumque aspernatur esse explicabo ea sit incidunt molestiae tempore? Laudantium molestiae qui obcaecati dignissimos?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure debitis corporis cum nemo ex, soluta hic ratione obcaecati corrupti quas quod, laborum itaque consequatur, sint enim voluptatum dolore aliquam eum. Doloribus perspiciatis non debitis cum cumque
  iste magnam architecto labore, veritatis fugit omnis eius maiores earum molestias aliquam facilis sint ea facere corrupti quae placeat deserunt incidunt eveniet ad! Aut. Itaque atque minus dignissimos nostrum earum modi, nemo error, placeat est quas
  deserunt ducimus magni. Facilis cumque aspernatur esse explicabo ea sit incidunt molestiae tempore? Laudantium molestiae qui obcaecati dignissimos?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure debitis corporis cum nemo ex, soluta hic ratione obcaecati corrupti quas quod, laborum itaque consequatur, sint enim voluptatum dolore aliquam eum. Doloribus perspiciatis non debitis cum cumque
  iste magnam architecto labore, veritatis fugit omnis eius maiores earum molestias aliquam facilis sint ea facere corrupti quae placeat deserunt incidunt eveniet ad! Aut. Itaque atque minus dignissimos nostrum earum modi, nemo error, placeat est quas
  deserunt ducimus magni. Facilis cumque aspernatur esse explicabo ea sit incidunt molestiae tempore? Laudantium molestiae qui obcaecati dignissimos?</p>
```